# Get single item data by ID in angular JS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have articles which i'm getting from my API. My API lists them correctly when i go to http://localhost:60367/api/article/ and gets the correct data correctly for a single item when i go to http://localhost:60367/api/article/1

Using angular, how get the data for one of these articles by it's id so that if i go to my angular app and click to http://localhost:60300/perspectives/1/ I get the data of that one item. ( fyi, When i go to the index http://localhost:60300/perspectives/ I get the data accordingly.  )

Please assist, my app.js file is below:

```
 var url = "http://localhost:60367/api/article";

 var modules = ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'];
 var App = angular.module("App", modules);

// Route providers
   App.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // Get route for perspectives homepage
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/articles-home.html', 
        controller: ArticleController})
        // Get route for perspectives single page
        .when("/:id/", {templateUrl: 'partials/articles-single.html', 
        controller: ArticleController})
        .otherwise({ redirectTo : "/"})

   // Use the HTML5 History API
      $locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false});
   });

// Controller
   var ArticleController = function ($scope, $http, $log) {
    // For onsuccess, also do console.log for $log property
    var onSuccess = function (response) {$scope.articles = response.data; 
   $log.info(response);};
    var onFailure = function (reason) {$scope.error = 
    reason;$log.info(reason);};

    // Get all students and display them in index
    var getAllArticles = function () {$http.get(url).then(onSuccess, 
    onFailure)};
    getAllArticles();
    // Get single student by Id
    // 
    // 
  };
 App.controller("ArticleController", ArticleController);
```

**SOLUTION**:

Ok this is how I solved it, I created a new controller for the single item and wrote it manually like this:

```
var SingleArticleController = function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$http({
    url: "http://localhost:60367/api/article/{id}",
    params: { id: $routeParams.id },
    method: "get"
})
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.article = response.data;
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams):

> What I've outline here will allow you to use the same controller here as that's what you've show in your config. Often-times, you'd assign a separate controller in your route (something like `ArticleController`, `ArticleListController`.). If you do that, the same process applies, but you wouldn't need to check if you have an `ID` parameter.

**In your Controller:**

```
  // Add $routeParams
  .controller('ArticleController', function($scope, $routeParams) {

    // Get the id
    var id = $routeParams.id;

    // Set url based on whether or not you have an ID
    var fullUrl = id ? url + '/' + id : url;

    var getAllArticles = function() {
      $http.get(fullUrl).then(onSuccess,
        onFailure)
    };

  })
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work, I get the same thing displays nothing for my curly bracket fields {{ }}, i've tried separating the controllers as well

Comment: You're going to want to update onSuccess to reflect what your model looks like. You may need two. Try console.logging your $http responses first to see what they look like. That's why this is normally two controllers, usually you have one object or a list of objects.

Comment: Thanks, have pasted my solution above in OP